# Remove top space on mobile nav bar

Tags: wordpress, navbar, responsive

Hello everybody I'm new here. Thanks in advance that this platform exists!

I built a Wordpress website using a theme (and child theme) and there's a weird empty space at the top of all pages of the website only in the mobile version. The entire mobile website starts like 50 pixels lower than it should be...

I checked there's no top bar assigned so I don't see how to remove this empty top space. Any leads?

Here's the URL: https://livewithauthenticity.com

Thanks in advance

PS: this problem doesn't happen in Desktop version, only on mobile
PS2: thanks Gazi for finding out that the issue occurs only when logged in (to any account)

Comment: there is no empty top space

Comment: its happening when you are logged in? because as a guest I don't see any space there? Maybe wp-admin bar check this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-the-28px-push-down-from-the-admin-bar/

Comment: I can't seem to see any top space. The website looks really good, by the way. Way to go!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Gazi you are right, it happens only when I'm logged in. Good point. I still don't see why but hope this info helps

Comment: Hello again any leads please? Thanks